# Build error when using pipe related functions in openCL code

Tags: opencl

I am writing to use the pipe feature of opencl 2.0. I have a kernel which filters the input and writes into a pipe. But the issue is that when i use pipe related functions i get the error "function  declared implicitly". When i checked online i found that this error usualy appears in c code if the function is not declared before its used. But this is an openCL library function.

My kernel code is:

__kernel void filter1_kernel(__global int *input, const unsigned int rLen, const unsigned int lower, const unsigned int upper, __global int *pipe1){

```
unsigned int bitmap = 0;
int count = 0;
//reserve_id_t rid;

uint numWorkItems = get_global_size(0);
uint tid          = get_global_id(0);
uint num_packets = get_local_size(0);

while(tid < rLen){
    if(input[tid] >= lower && input[tid] <= upper){
        bitmap = bitmap | (1 << count);
        printf((__constant char *)"\nfilter1 %u %u %d %u", tid, bitmap, input[tid], count);
    }
    tid += numWorkItems;
    count++;
}

reserve_id_t rid = work_group_reserve_write_pipe(pipe1, num_packets);
while(is_valid_reserve_id(rid) == false) {
    rid = work_group_reserve_write_pipe(pipe1, num_packets);
}
//write to pipe
```

}

The errors that i got are:

Build Log Buffer length : 1048
                                --- Build log ---
"C:\Users\pdca\AppData\Local\Temp\OCLFB5E.tmp.cl", line 40: error: function
          "work_group_reserve_write_pipe" declared implicitly
        reserve_id_t rid = work_group_reserve_write_pipe(pipe1, num_packets);
                           ^

"C:\Users\pdca\AppData\Local\Temp\OCLFB5E.tmp.cl", line 40: warning: a value
          of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type
          "reserve_id_t"
        reserve_id_t rid = work_group_reserve_write_pipe(pipe1, num_packets);
                           ^

"C:\Users\pdca\AppData\Local\Temp\OCLFB5E.tmp.cl", line 41: error: function
          "is_valid_reserve_id" declared implicitly
        while(is_valid_reserve_id(rid) == false) {
              ^

"C:\Users\pdca\AppData\Local\Temp\OCLFB5E.tmp.cl", line 42: warning: a value
          of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "reserve_id_t"
                rid = work_group_reserve_write_pipe(pipe1, num_packets);
                    ^

2 errors detected in the compilation of "C:\Users\pdca\AppData\Local\Temp\OCLFB5
E.tmp.cl".
Frontend phase failed compilation.

```
                            --- Build log ---
```

ERROR: clBuildProgram (CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the CL-specs (https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-2.0.pdf), page 203:

> If the cl-std build option is not specified, the highest OpenCL C 1.x language version supported by each device is used when compiling the program for each device. Applications are required to specify the
>   –cl-std=CL2.0 option if they want to compile or build their programs
>   with OpenCL C 2.0.

So if you did not include this option to your `clBuildProgram()` call, the CL-compiler will not recognize any 2.0 language-features. Thus, your call should look sth like this:

```
clBuildProgram (program, num_devices, device_list, "–cl-std=CL2.0", NULL, NULL);
```

In addition, I think your kernel-parameter is not correct. You cannot use a `__global int *pipe1` as an argument for the pipe functions. It should probably be declared as `__write_only pipe int pipe1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But after i adding the option -cl-std=CL2.0 and changing the parameter as you said the clBuildProgram fails with the message "flex scanner jammed".

Comment: The build command i used is:

cl_err = clBuildProgram(program[Q6_PROGRAM_ID], 1, &device[A10_GPU], "-I ./ -cl-std=CL2.0", NULL, NULL);


And the parameter was changed as:

__kernel void filter1_kernel(__global int *input, const unsigned int rLen, const unsigned int lower, const unsigned int upper, __write_only pipe int pipe1){

Comment: Whoa, "flex scanner jammed" sounds like "internal compiler error". Don't know WTH is going on there...

Comment: Wait! Did you copy&paste the cl-std option from my post? Because I copy&pasted it from the PDF-document. AND looking at the screen closely, I notice that the first hyphen looks different than the other! I think it may be a different character! Try typing the option manually please!

Comment: I am using AMD OpenCL SDK 3.0.0-Beta. Could the issue be withe the SDK?

Comment: Mhm, dunno. Perhaps at that point you might try to strip your kernel-source down to a super-minimal dummy-kernel (with no fancy pipes, nothing) and see if the build-problem persists. Other than that: did you check if your device actually supports Version 2.0?

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for helping me out. I had a print statement inside my kernel which i was using for debugging purpose. That statement was creating the issue. So now i removed it and the program works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Althought i wonder why the compiler cant handle the printf statement.

Comment: To be fair, the printf statement looks a bit odd, too. Did you try it without the cast, i.e. `printf("\nfilter1 %u %u %d %u", tid, bitmap, input[tid], count);` instead of `printf((__constant char *)"\nfilter1 %u %u %d %u", tid, bitmap, input[tid], count);`?

Comment: I did. It doesnt work. I checked online and someone suggested to add the cast. Thats why i added it. Printf worked only after i added the cast